# Image resizing when opened in a separate tap

Tags: html, css, image, resize

Hee all,

**Browser behaviour image**

If an image is opened in a browser (Chrome, Safari, or Firefox). When resizing the browser window the image is also being resized. When inspecting the element it seems that the browser is updating the `width` and `height` property of the image tag to accomplish this. The strange thing is I don't see any scripts loaded in that could cause this behaviour.

To reproduce this behaviour:

- open the following link (https://theawesomedaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/the-most-important-image-on-the-internet-5-1.jpg) or any other url that links to an image,
- resize the browser window

**Problem**

I would like to replicate this behaviour where it updates the `width` and the `height` properties when the browser window is changed. But when I copy the html and css from the link above and paste it into my own html file it doesn't work the same. Below is what my html file looks like:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page with image</title>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0">
  <img style="margin: auto; display: block" width="750" height="750" src="https://theawesomedaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/the-most-important-image-on-the-internet-5-1.jpg" />
</body>

</html>
```

**Questions**

1. Does anyone know what the browser is using to recalculate the `width` and `height` values of the image?
2. Does anyone know how I can use this capability on my own page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the browser loads this code, but it must be using the ResizeObserver.

```
<html lang="en" style="background-color: #fff">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page with image</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1"
    />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon.svg" />
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0">
    <img
      id="image"
      style="margin: auto; display: block"
      width="750"
      height="750"
      src="https://theawesomedaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/the-most-important-image-on-the-internet-5-1.jpg"
    />
  </body>
  <script>
    const image = document.getElementById("image");
    const apsectRatio = 750 / 750;

    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach((element) => {
        const width = element.contentRect.width;

        if (width < 750) {
          image.width = width;
          image.height = width * apsectRatio;
        }
      });
    });

    resizeObserver.observe(document.body);
  </script>
</html>
```

This is what I would do.